# What is the real cause of the boiling (forming of bubbles) of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, evaporation, bubbles

I've got a question about the boiling of water. I'm a first year physics student and from the Netherlands.

I've searched alot about the boiling of water and this confused me. Everyone said something else about the cause of the boiling. Let me explain it further.

Let's say you want to cook some eggs. You put on the gas. 
1. As the temperature of the water increases, the evaporation increases. 
2. When the evaporation increases, the vapor pressure will increase too. When the vapor pressure is equal to the external pressure, there will form a bubble.

So, my question is: is this a chain/link of causes? So the first link causes the next one? So the temperature increase causes the evaporation to increase which causes the vapor pressure to increase which causes the forming of a bubble (the actual boiling)?

I doubt if it is a link of causes (the one thing causes the other) because they happen at the same time. And in my opinion a cause happens BEFORE the consequence.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfagHzOtIDM
In this video they say boiling has more causes. What are these causes?

When the boiling point is reached, there happen two things:
- 100 degree celcius
- vapor pressure that equals the external pressure

Are they both causes of the boiling (coming up of the bubbles)? Or is the vapor pressure that equals the external pressure the cause?

Comment: You're boiling the water using an electric plate? So the source of heat energy is restricted to the bottom of your pot? That induces some temperature gradient that may well explain what you are seeing. Put the pot into an oven where it is heated from all sides almost equally to see the difference.

Comment: No, I was looking for the actual cause of the boiling of water. Is it the temperature or the vapor pressure that equals the external pressure? Or are they both causes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "boiling"? Forming bubbles, for one, or, more generally, changing state from liquid to gas? Note that the liquid/gas transition is not only governed by temperature alone, but also by pressure. At see level, water boils at 100°C, but on mount Everest 60°C is enough. On Mars, 40°C are enough (don't start a law suit if the actual figures are somewhat different). Keyword is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram

Comment: Yes, I mean the formation or nucleation of bubbles. Do you say that vapor pressure is the true cause of the formation of bubbles? Or the combination of temperature (depending on the location) AND vapor pressure?

Can i say that the temperature (100 or i.e. 60 at mount everest) causes the vapor pressure to equal the external pressure? Or isnt it a cause because they happen at the same time?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't have a complete, satisfying understanding of that. But I am good enough to throw some buzzwords at you ;-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheating is one of it.

Comment: They say ''the temperature must be high enough that the vapor pressure exceeds the ambient pressure (the atmospheric pressure, primarily). Below that temperature, a water vapor bubble will shrink and vanish.''
Do I interpret it right when I say that it's always the combination of a high enough temperature AND a vapor pressure that exceeds the ambient pressure? You don't see it in isolation right? That you see a high enough temperature but not a high enough vapor pressure in example.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a combination of temperature **and** pressure. And in your pot on the hearth, temperature (heating from below) and pressure (augmented by the water column in the pot) compete if vapor is formed. Additional effects may promote or delay the forming of actual bubbles. (See superheating.)

Comment: Can you explain why it definetly is the combination of the two? Am I wrong when I think that the temperature causes the vapor pressure to equal the external pressure? Thus the vapor pressure is the ''last'' cause in the link of causal factors?  Or doesn't the temperature causes the vapor pressure to rise but they happen together at the same time? So it isn't a cause at all?

Comment: Please excuse me when I ever just heard that and just *believed it* (shame on me). I remember an equation that links those values to each other, but best of what I can find now is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_point  (really wondering if I'm the only one that has seen this question).

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with this equation? I don't get it to be honest, too newb for that, haha.

Comment: Yea, I've been away from that for quite awhile myself, had to do some net research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_gas_law is what connects volume, temperature and pressure. (I could only remember the outcome, not the reason why).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram gives another clue on how (solid/liquid/gas) and pressure/temperature is linked.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this really helps alot. Still I'm not enough into this literature to really understand it. Can you translate it a bit in understandable language for me? I can't make up if they say that the first (temperature) causes the other (pressure) or that it happens at the same time.

Comment: The vapour pressure rises due to the temperature increase, this is described by the [Clausius-Clapeyron equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius-Clapeyron_equation). Once the vapour pressure reaches the atmospheric pressure the liquid is no longer a stable phase. For actual boiling to happen, you further need nucleation sites (or sufficient superheating), as the surface tension of the liquid suppresses bubbles with very small radii.

Comment: As far as I can remember (I've been out of this business a really *long* time and therefor might be mistaken and fooled by false memories), but the *boiling point* is really a function that has pressure *and* temperature  as an argument. The more pressure you apply, the more harder it gets for any molecule to leave the liquid to gas, and the higher the temperature is, the more energy is available to a molecule to do so. Loosely speaking, pressure increases the "costs" to change from liquid to gas, but temperature increases the "money" available.

Comment: Last question, what do you mean with ''note that the liquid/gas transition is not only governed by temperature alone, but also by pressure.''. What do you mean with governed by? You referred to the mount everest. Can you explain in this example why the temperature isn't the only one who ''controls'' the boiling? I'm sorry for not understanding, I think that my english isn't good enough.

Comment: ''note that the liquid/gas transition is not only governed by temperature alone, but also by pressure.''

What did you mean with governed by? Do you mean that liquid boils at 100C (at sea level) because the temperature is 100C AND the pressure is  101,325 Pa? When it was only because of the temperature being 100C, the boiling point would be the same at every location on earth.

Comment: there is a misunderstanding about the word vapour pressure here, I think. I explained it in my answer, I hope.

Comment: Did the answers address your question about what is the cause of what. Please accept an answer if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 8):

> When the vapor pressure is equal to the external pressure, there will form a bubble.

Not true.   Instead, when the vapor pressure is equal to the external pressure, then any *existing* bubbles will begin growing continuously.

And, if no bubbles are already present, then the water will superheat far above the boiling temperature, yet no bubbles will appear.  For vapor pressure to exist within water, first gas pockets must exist within water.  We need gas-fluid interfaces.  Without these, all boiling takes place silently, at the surface where water touches air.

Beware of common misconceptions.  Boiling-bubbles are typically not seeded by dirt or contamination. ("Mythbusters" show got it wrong![1]) Instead, boiling is seeded by existing micro-bubbles trapped in small crevices.  So, yes, your coffee heated in a microwave oven can superheat and explode, even though coffee is very impure water. If the surface of your ceramic mug lacks air-filled micro-scratches, the coffee will not boil until its temperature is raised far above 100C. But liquids may refuse to boil even when up against a very rough surface, if that surface has been previously wetted with water over 100C. The hot water fills the microscopic roughness with steam, which then condenses, removing any air pockets that let the rough surface act like a "seed" for roiling boil.  A fully-wetted rough surface won't prevent superheating.

On a typical stove with a metal pot, the metal bottom will be heated far above 100C, even though the water has not yet approached 100C.  The metal surface will be covered with spontaneous steam pockets, but these bubbles cannot grow, since they're right against cooler, under-100C water. When the main volume of water reaches 100C, seed-bubbles are already present on the hot metal, so the pot will immediately begin a visible boil.  But without this large temperature excursion at the metal surface, visible boiling may not commence.

Often with new glass cookware, (with no scratches,) and with water heated on a gas stove (with no tiny hot-spots,) the water won't boil.  Instead it superheats far above 100C, then unexpectedly produces a few spontaneous micro-bubbles, and exhibits the boiling-explosions called "bumping."  The explosions may splash boiling water out of the container.  Sometimes they're violent enough to shatter glass.  To prevent this, use 'boiling stones' sold in laboratory supply catalogs.  Or with microwaved coffee, provide a dry, air-filled wooden stir-stick.  These cause a roiling boil at 100C, which cools the bulk liquid and halts superheating.

The 'boiling stones' commonly used to prevent bumping-explosions in laboratory glassware won't work if cooled and then quickly re-used.  This happens because all their internal crevices become filled with water.  No small bubbles, no "boiling seeds." Restore your 'boiling stones' before re-use, by allowing them to dry thoroughly so the air again fills all of their internal pockets.  Or, use a 150C drying oven to rapidly boil off their trapped water.   Similarly, a sodden, well-boiled wooden stick in your microwave coffee may stop working.  So turn it over and use the dry end!

[1]Big caveat: if micro-bubbles aren't present anywhere, then superheated water will continue to rise in temperature, finally boiling spontaneously with explosive violence. The "seed" or "trigger" for this boiling can be:  intrusion of a dry object, vibration and sound waves, thermal fluctuations, ionization from background radiation, and yes, suspended particles, surface roughness, and contamination.  Mythbusters(tm) did have it right, but only regarding extremely superheated water.  When we first eliminate all surface micro-bubbles and then raise the temperature far past boiling, eventually something will trigger a steam-explosion. The center of this explosive vapor-production might be a tiny grain of dirt, or a pencil tapping against the container, or even a cosmic-ray strike.

Comment: wbeaty is right, and if you are designing thermal inkjet printheads and get the nanoscale surface texture of the microscopic heaters wrong, the bubble nucleation process (which propels the ink droplets out the nozzles in such a device) will occur at the wrong superheat temperature and the ejected droplets of ink will have the wrong size and velocity.

Comment: @wbeaty can u please explain to a high school student{which is me} how on adding "ideal solute" would decrease this inside bubble vapor pressure and in turn would increase the boiling point? I used to think it somehow attracts water molecules more strongly than the intermolecular force between water molecules themselves but then I thought if its ideal solute and it won't change the bonding so it shouldn't change the vapor pressure so what's going on? I know it would change the concentration but how "inside bubble pressure depends on the concentration"?

Comment: also the inside bubble pressure is due to both vapors and air right? so I think the pressure inside the bubbles would be equal to 1atm even when the temperature is not 100 degrees,,,,because air was already there?? also why at boiling the the temperature of water becomes constant? how this relation that "vapor pressure=external pressure" indicates that the temperature would become constant at boiling point{i.e when the bubble begins to grow}?

Comment: I think it should increase continously and produce mor and more inside bubble pressure?? some says at this temperature water molecules changes move apart and changes state  ,,,so if that's the case why not all water molecules becomes vapor simultaneously at 100 degrees? and also why they even become vapors at other temperatures when there temeprature is not even 100 degrees?

Comment: 3) why they don't change into vapors and form inside bubbles when there are no nucleation sites,,,I mean at 100 degrres water molecules should still separate and form bubbles right?

Comment: @ArunBhardwaj It's nonlinear, since water molecules "stick" to neighbors.  If a molecule is surrounded, it has nowhere to go, and the liquid can superheat.  If a molecule is at the surface of a (large) existing bubble, it can launch free, evaporate.  (And, any too-small bubbles will shrink and vanish because their surface is too curved, molecules on surface are too surrounded by neighbors, causing loose gas molecules to be trapped if they touch the surface, even if far above 100C.)

Answer (score 5):

While the answer of wbeaty is very interesting in showing points relevant in practice, I think all the answers are still missing an important and simple theoretical point, which you should consider to understand the process.

**vapour pressure** does mean two different things as used above. First, the pressure, the existing water vapour would have (if it were alone) - let's call it the partial pressure of the water. And secondly, the maximal possible vapour pressure (a function of temperatue) - let's call it the saturation pressure.

The latter is easy to understand qualitatively:
If you have a surface between water and vapour, you have two random processes: particles hop out of the surface into the gas, and particles from the gas get caught in the water. After some time, there will be equillibrium of these processes. The first process depends mainly on temperature (how fast are the water particles), the second mainly on the pressure (how often do vapour particles hit the surface).
There has thus to be some function $p(T)$ or $T(p)$ which describes these two *at equillibrium*. This is the abovementioned saturation pressure.

Over every water surface there is some vapour, and after a while it has the saturation pressure - if nothing moves to blow it away. If you blow on your soup to cool it, that's the point: to remove vapour, reduce its partial pressure, and thus enable the water to evaporate further.
Note: the net pressure of the air is always atmospheric, you just change the part of it produced by water and the other part produced by the rest gases.

Now, what happens if the saturation pressure gets greater than the atmospheric?
There is no need to blow anymore! The vapour can just push the atmosphere away, it doesn't have to wait, it just takes the place it need to evaporate into. That's boiling.

---

PS: concerning the concept of partial pressure.
The necessary asumption for this concept is, that we deal with ideal gases. The particles do not interact, they just bump against the walls and thus produce the pressure. The net pressure is just the sum of the pressures each part of the gas produces. I.e., each part of the gas would have if it were alone at that temperature in that volume.

For an ideal gas you know: $pV=nRT$
So since $p$ is proportional to $n$ it means, that $n_1$ of oxygen and $n_2$ of nitrogen will produce the sum of the pressures each part does by itself.
Mark: this is not self-evident, it's a concequence of the proportionality between $p$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the vapor pressure equaling the external pressure that is the cause, and not the temperature (except to the extent that it determines the vapor pressure).  When the vapor pressure is equal to the external pressure, bubbles can begin forming under the liquid, and the atmosphere can be pushed back at the upper surface of the liquid to accommodate the additional volume of the bubbles within the liquid.  The heating and temperature changes that take place before the temperature reaches the required value (for the vapor pressure to equal the external pressure) does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You say the external pressure is the cause. Does this mean that first the temperature reaches the required value (boiling point) and later the vapor pressure equals the external pressure. Is this right? So the temperature is the cause of the vapor pressure to equal the external pressure, the external pressure is the cause of the forming of bubbles. 
Is the reaching of the temperature level the exact moment that vapor pressure is at the required value? Of is it that first the temperature reaches the value, and later the vapor pressure reaches the value?

Comment: The temperature and vapor pressure reach the required value at the same time.  Before this, the temperature is lower, and the vapor pressure is not high enough to match the external pressure.  The vapor pressure is a unique function of temperature, and so the temperature and vapor pressure vary in tandem.

Comment: Okay, that's clear. But why isn't the temperature a cause too then? You say they vary in tandem. Aren't they both causes then? Or is the temperature the cause of the vapor pressure, and the vapor pressure the cause of the bubbles to form?

Comment: The latter is the correct mechanism.

Comment: Okay, thanks. 

Do the water vapor's leave the water to join the bubble before the reaching of 100C? Because the vapor pressure is reached at 100C at the exact same time, right? So the joining of the bubble (increasing of the vapor pressure) has to occur before the 100C. Because if they would leave the bulk AT the time of reaching 100C, the vapor pressure equalling the external pressure would occur a bit later than reaching 100C.

When the temperature is below 100C, the bubbles CAN grow but they will collapse because of the external pressure, right?

Comment: I don't follow everything you're saying, but, yes, bubbles can only grow once the equilibrium vapor pressure at the temperature of the liquid reaches the external temperature.  The temperature doesn't have to be 100 C if the total external pressure differs from 1 atm.  For example, someone previously mentioned that, at the top of Mt. Everest, water can boil at 60 C because the atmospheric pressure is lower.

Comment: When the average kinetic energy increases, the temperature increases. But when the average kinetic energy increases, more water molecules will leave the bulk and join a bubble, this makes the vapor pressure grow. The process of leaving the bulk and joining a bubble will take some time, so the vapor pressure will increase a bit later after the kinetic energy increases, do you get what I mean?

Comment: No I don't.  This makes no sense to me.  The equilibrium vapor pressure is a unique function of the temperature of the liquid.  The equilibrium vapor pressure responds instantly to the temperature at the surface of a bubble.

Comment: Let's say the temperature starts to increase, the energy of the molecules starts too increase immedetiatly. Doesn't it take a milisecond or a second to become a vapor and travel to the bubble to join the bubble?

Comment: The liquid is immediately adjacent to the bubble, and the molecules of liquid at the interface between the bubble and the liquid do not have to travel anywhere to enter the bubble.  In my judgment, you're talking about negligible effects.  I think that my discussion and comments are not answering you in a way that resonates with your way of viewing things.  I'm going to drop out of our discussion and let someone else take over with a different perspective.

Comment: This did answer my questions, thank you for that. I really appreciate your input. Thanks alot for your help, Chester.

Comment: Chester, last question. Let's say there is a very small increasing of the temperature, from 90.0C to 90.1C. At the moment the temperature starts rising, is that the exact moment that the water molecule will break free from it's IMF and joins the bubble?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are complicating the process a bit too much.  As noted in the earlier response: boiling occurs when the vapor pressure of the liquid reaches the surrounding pressure (e.g. of atmosphere or atmosphere + pressure of overlying liquid (heating usually done from bottom)).  Evaporation, in the context of initiation of boiling, serves only to carry heat away and reduce the temperature rate of rise ("a watched pot never boils").  You can attain boiling in two ways: heat the liquid or reduce the overlying pressure.  Put water into a sealed container and draw a vacuum on it, and it will boil at room temperature...
Water at room temperature has a vapor pressure (a few mm Hg pressure) - by heating it you are only raising it's vapor pressure until it reaches the atmospheric pressure (at your current elevation - at higher elevation, water boils at a lower temperature).  Once boiling is achieved, the temperature will not increase further - because you are removing heat through evaporation as fast as you are putting heat into the liquid from the external heat source.

There is one other added complexity as well: in order for a vapor bubble to form, the vapor pressure must overcome the surface tension of the water in order to make a "hole" in the water.  When the water is very pure, and the container surface is very smooth, it can be difficult for vapor bubbles to form and the water can become superheated - this is why, in chemistry lab, boiling chips are placed in beakers - the ceramic chips provide nucleation points for vapor bubbles to form and avoid superheating the water.

Answer (score -1):

Boiling, liquid starts to vapourize which means sufficient heat is provided break the inter-molecular bonds. the temperature at which the inter molecular bond breaks will be called as boiling point of that liquid.Breaking of the bonds results in the formation of bubbles i.e liquid  is broken into gases.